# Magento2 How to get region name by id?

Tags: magento2, model, country-regions

Like in magento1 is is there any method to retrive region name by id.

```
$regionModel = Mage::getModel('directory/region')->load('region_id'); 
$region = $regionModel->getName();
```

I checked respective class(`Magento\Directory\Model\Region`) but didn't find any method there.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You still can do basically the same as `load()`, `save()`, and `delete()` actions still exists in abstract model classes. They are however marked as `deprecated` as magento moves CRUD methods to separate `repositories` classes. But since directory model does not have them yet here are 2 ways of loading the region.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$region = $objectManager->create('Magento\Directory\Model\Region')
                        ->load($regionId);
```

or with collection

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$region = $objectManager->create('Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Region\Collection')
                        ->addFieldToFilter('region_id', ['eq' => $regionId])
                        ->getFirstItem();
```

This is just proof-of-concept code. Direct use of object manager is discouraged so in your actual code you should inject the proper class with dependency injection in `__construct()` class.

Comment: Great. Its work.

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve this goal using a collection and the getItemById() method. Something like that:

```
<?php

use Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Region\Collection  as RegionCollection;

class Example
{
    /** @var RegionCollection  */
    private $regionCollection;
    
    public function __construct(
        RegionCollection $regionCollection
    ) {
        $this->regionCollection = $regionCollection;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $id
     * @return string
     */
    private function getRegionNameById(int $id): string
    {
        $region = $this->regionCollection->getItemById($id);

        return $region->getCode();
    }
}
```

See you later!