# how to get Region name instead of its value?

Tags: magento2.4.3

I'm trying to get fetch Region Name instead of its value, from select option,
but I get the only region value not its name,

I have created a select option in the system.xml

below is my code,

**System.xml**

```
<field id="gstregion" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="6" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Production State</label>
                <comment><![CDATA[Select the Origin State.]]></comment>                 
                <source_model>Test\Code\Model\Config\Region\RegionInformationProvider</source_model>
                <depends>
                    <field id="GSTtax/GSTtax/status">1</field>
                </depends>
            </field>
```

**app/code/Test/Code/Model/Config/Region**

```
<?php
namespace Test\Code\Model\Config\Region;

class RegionInformationProvider
{
  protected $countryInformationAcquirer;
  protected $addressRepository;

  public function __construct(
      \Magento\Directory\Api\CountryInformationAcquirerInterface $countryInformationAcquirer
  ) {
         $this->countryInformationAcquirer = $countryInformationAcquirer;
  }

  public function toOptionArray()
  {
        $countries = $this->countryInformationAcquirer->getCountriesInfo();
        foreach ($countries as $country) {
            if($country->getId() == 'IN'){
                $regions = [];
                if ($availableRegions = $country->getAvailableRegions()) {
                     foreach ($availableRegions as $region) {
                          $regions[] = [
                             'value' => $region->getId(),
                             'label' => $region->getName()
                           ];
                     }
                 }
            }  
        }
        return $regions;

     }
}
```

**Data.php**

```
const CONFIG_GST_REGION           = 'GSTtax/GSTtax/gstregion';

public function getGstRegion()
    {
        $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
        return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::CONFIG_GST_REGION, $storeScope);
    }
```

**test.phtml**

```
$state = $this->helper('Test\Code\Helper\Data')->getGstRegion();    
echo $state;
```

**`<option value="580" id="optIdqnoKrZDb" selected="selected">Gujarat</option>`**

**Output => 580**

**not Gujarat**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this line from

```
'value' => $region->getId(),
```

to

```
'value' => $region->getName(),
```

then check

Comment: not worked yet, i have changed as per your answer.

Comment: did you save the region again from configuration again and flush the cache?

Comment: yes, i have doing it same, but its not worked, its only give me a value

Comment: now its work, thanks you saved my time

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will get this id as value getting store is value not name.

So you have to get the name of that region. Pass your $state into this will load out all data related to the id

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$region = $objectManager->create('Magento\Directory\Model\Region')
                        ->load($state);

$region->getName();
```

**Note** Please avoid use of object manager

This might help you.
More Information: [Link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/183891/magento2-how-to-get-region-name-by-id)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this is the correct way to show the region option

```
<?php
namespace Test\Code\Model\Config\Region;

class RegionInformationProvider
{
  protected $_regionsFactory;
  protected $country;

  public function __construct(
      \Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Region\CollectionFactory $regionsFactory,
      \Magento\Directory\Model\Country $country

  ) {
        $this->_regionsFactory = $regionsFactory;
        $this->country = $country;
  }

     public function toOptionArray() {
        $regions = [];
        $regionCollection = $this->country->loadByCode('IN')->getRegions();
        $regions = $regionCollection->loadData()->toOptionArray(false);
        foreach ($regions as $region){
            $regions[] = [
                            'value' => $region['label'],
                            'label' => $region['label']
                        ];
         } 

        return $regions;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the username you can follow the below code.

```
use Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Region\Collection  as RegionCollection;

class Example
{
    /** @var RegionCollection  */
    private $regionCollection;
    
    public function __construct(
        RegionCollection $regionCollection
    ) {
        $this->regionCollection = $regionCollection;
    }

   
    private function getRegionName()
    {
        $region = $this->regionCollection->getData();
        foreach ($regions as $region) {
            $regionName = $region['name'];
        }
    }
}
```